# How Do I Join Records In LINQ?

Tags: linq, join

I am new to LINQ and am trying to sort this one out. 
I am trying to grab records for multiple accounts (multiple account ids)
and sort the results according to the date.

What I have currently is putting the results in a list
such that multiple rows / account are contained in each list item.

This is close but not exactly what I want. How do I return results such that **all results** (that is, all the records associated with each account) are sorted together by date and returned as such.

I imagine that this is some sort of LINQ join but I am not sure what the syntax would be.

```
public List<StatusUpdate> GetFriendStatusUpdatesByAccountId(Int32 accountId)
        {
            List<StatusUpdate> result;

            List<Friend> friends =
                _friendRepository.GetFriendsByAccountId(accountId);

            using (WorkbookDataContext dc = _conn.GetContext())
            {
                IEnumerable<StatusUpdate> statusUpdates = null;

                foreach (Friend friend in friends)
                {
                    Friend friend1 = friend;

                    statusUpdates = from su in dc.StatusUpdates
                                    where su.AccountId == friend1.MyFriendsAccountId
                                    orderby su.CreateDate descending
                                    select su;
                }

                if (statusUpdates != null) result = statusUpdates.ToList();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Thanks for your suggestion. I have reworked it a little bit in order to have access
to OrderByDescending but can't seem to figure out the "cannot resolve symbol" 
problem for *friend* and *su* (shown below in CAPS). I am wondering if you were assuming that "friend in friends" was accessing Friend as the LINQ table (which would give
us access to MyFriendsAccountId) and not List (which does not give us direct
access to MyFriendsAccountId? Anyway, I am a LINQ newb so, maybe I am barking up the 
wrong tree. At any rate, FRIEND in friends and SU are throwing the "cannot resolve 
symbol error" and I'd appreciate suggestions. Thanks a ton for your feedback...

```
public List<StatusUpdate> GetFriendStatusUpdatesByAccountId(Int32 accountId)
        {
            List<StatusUpdate> result;

            using (WorkbookDataContext dc = _conn.GetContext())
            {
                List<Friend> friends =
                _friendRepository.GetFriendsByAccountId(accountId);

                IEnumerable<StatusUpdate> statusUpdates = 
                    from su in dc.StatusUpdates
                    join friend in friends
                    on FRIEND.MyFriendsAccountId
                    equals SU.AccountId
                    select su;

                    result = 
                        statusUpdates.OrderByDescending
                        (su => su.CreateDate).ToList();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: see my updated answer, the fix is just to switch the friend.MyFriendAccountId and su.AccountId in the join clause

Comment: thanks - that did the job. I have a final error with this one posted below... still working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by what you're trying to do, your code seems to overwrite the *statusUpdates* variable inside the *foreach* loop and by the look of it, result will always get you the sorted status updates for the LAST friend in the *friends* list.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have a many-to-one relationship between Friend and Account ID, and each Friend has a number of StatusUpdate, and you want to get all the StatusUpdate associated with all the Friends that share the same Account ID, and have them sorted by CreatedDate descending?

If that's the case, I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
public List<StatusUpdate> GetFriendStatusUpdatesByAccountId(Int32 accountId)
{
    List<StatusUpdate> result;

    List<Friend> friends = _friendRepository.GetFriendsByAccountId(accountId);

    using (WorkbookDataContext dc = _conn.GetContext())
    {
        var statusUpdates = 
           from su in dc.StatusUpdates
           join friend in friends on su.AccountId equals friend.MyFriendsAccountId
           select su;

        return statusUpdates.OrderByDescending(su => su.CreateDate)
                            .ToList();
    }
}
```

You can equally do the join using lambda expressions, but I usually favor the linq query syntax when it comes to joins as they are cleaner.

Hope this gives you what you want, if you're looking for some more examples on doing joins in linq, I've got a few examples [here](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/02/linq-lambda-expression-vs-query-expression/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your response. I really appreciate it. I have posted my followup questions above. Thanks again!

Comment: I've updated my answer, friend and su's place in the join clause needs to be switched, that's all

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate it. I am currently grappling with this error "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator." at this line: return statusUpdates.OrderByDescending(su => su.CreateDate).ToList(); I am trying to figure it out and will confirm your answer when I do. But, if I haven't when you read this and you know what is going on, I'd appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't have it yet but feel that the following is the right direction but it is complaining that the type arguments for 'Contains' cannot be inferred from its usage: IEnumerable<StatusUpdate> statusUpdates = dc.StatusUpdates.Where(update => friends.Contains(update.AccountId))
                        .Select(update => update);

Comment: you could use where instead of the join, but your where clause is wrong because elements in friends is of the type Friend not AccountId. Also, if you're not doing any projection in your select (turning the elements returned in the previous where clause into a different value) you don't need the select clause at the end.

Comment: maybe you could have a preceding query which gives you all the unique MyFriendAccountId from the 'friends' list, e.g.:
var friendAccountIds = friends.Select(friend => friend.MyFriendAccountId).Distinct();
then use it in your where clause:
dc.StatusUpdates.Where(update => friendAccountIds.Contains(update.AccountId));
Let me know if this one works!

Comment: Thanks again. Your code looks promising but I am getting the same error on friendAccountIds.Contains: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<TSource> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments. Sorry - I am sort of out of my comfort zone with LINQ. Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: What types are Friend.MyFriendAccountId and StatusUpdate.AccountId?

Comment: MyFriendsAccountId is of type int and AccountId is a nullable type (int?)

Comment: there's your problem, the two are different types, try modifying the where clause to something like this:
dc.StatusUpdates.Where(update => update.AccountId.HasValue && friendAccountIds.Contains(update.AccountId.Value));

Comment: that was it! thanks so much for sticking in there with me, very much appreciated. thank you!